# Django - What might cause the database to hang?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have devised a local network website using the Django framework and recently ran in problems I was not having until recently.
We are running experiments on a local network collecting various measurements and I set up this website to make sure we are collecting all the data in the same place.

I set up a PostGreSQL database and use django to populate it on the fly as I receive measurements. The script that does that looks like:

```
**ladrLogger.py**
#various imports
import django
from django.db import IntegrityError
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
django.setup()
from logger.models import Measurement, Device, Type , Room, Experiment, ExperimentData

def logDevice(self,port):
    # Callback function executed each time I receive data to log it in the database
    deviceData = port.data   # get the data
    # Do a bunch of tests and checks
    # ....
    # Get all measurement to add to the database
    # measurements is a list of measurement as defined in my django models
    measurements = self.prepareMeasurement(...)
    self.saveMeasurements(measurements)
    print "Saved measurements successfully."

def saveMeasurements(self,meas):
    if not meas:
        return
    elif type(meas) is list:
        for m in meas:
            self.saveMeasurements(m)
    elif type(meas) is Measurement:
        try:    
            meas.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            if 'unique constraint' in e.message:
                print "Skipping... Measurement already existed for device " + meas.device.name
            else:
                print "Skipping measurement due to error: " + e.message

def prepareMeasurement(self,nameDevice, typeDevice, time, data):
    ### Takes the characteristics of measurement (device, name and type) and creates the appropriate measurements.
    measurements = []
    m = Measurement()
    m.device = Device.objects.get(name=nameDevice)
    m.date = time
    # Bunch of tests
    # ..... 
    for idv,v in enumerate(value):
        if v in data:
            m = Measurement()
            m.device = something
            m.date = something else
            m.value = bla
            m.quantity = blabla
            measurements.append(m)
    return measurements

# Bunch of other methods
```

Note that this script is always running and waiting for more measurements to execute the logDevice callback.

EDIT: A custom based library based on YARP takes care of the callback handling. Code to create the callbacks looks like this:

```
portid = self.createPort(quer.group(1),True,True) #creates a port  
pyarp.connect(desc[0], self.fullPortPath(portid)) #establishes connection to talking port 
self.listenToPort(portid, lambda port: self.logDevice(port)) #tells him to execute that callback when he receives messages'
```

Callbacks are entirely dealt with in the background.

On the other hand, I have my django website that has various views displaying devices, measurements, plotting and whatnot.
The problem I have is that I am logging my measurements (about a few(2-3) per second at some times, usually less) and I can see that logging seems to be fine. But when I am calling my views, for example asking for the latest measurement for device x, I get an old measurement. One example of code:

```
def latestTemp(request,device_id):
    # Creates a csv file with the latest temperature measured
    #### for now does not check what measurements are actually available
    dev = get_object_or_404(Device, pk=device_id)
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.csv"' %dev.name
    #get measurement
    lastMeas = Measurement.objects.filter(device=dev, quantity=Type.objects.get(quantity='Temperature')).latest('date')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    # Form list of required timesteps
    date = lastMeas.date.astimezone(tz)
    writer.writerow([date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),date.strftime('%H:%M'),lastMeas.value])
    return response
```

EDIT (more precisions):
I have been logging data for a few hours, but the website only shows me something dating back a few hours. As I keep asking for that data, it gets more and more recent, as if it had been buffered somewhere and was now getting slowly is place and visible by the website, until everything finally comes back to normal. On the other hand, if I kill the logging process, the data seems lost for ever. What is strange though is that the logDevice method completes and I can see that the meas.save() commands were executed. I also tried to add a listener for the Django signal [post.save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/) and I catch them correctly.

Few information:
- I am using the postgresql backend
- I am running all of this on a dedicated Mac machine.
- let me know whatever else would be useful to know

My questions are:
- Do you se any reason that might happen (it used to not happen so I guess it might have to do with the database becoming big, 4Gb right now)
- As a side question, but maybe related, I suspect the way I am pushing new elements in the database is not really nice, since the code runs completely independently from the django website itself. Any suggestions on how to improve ? I thought the ladrLogger code could send a request to a dedicated view that create the new element but that might be heavier for no purpose.

EDIT: adding my models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    shortName = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True, default = "000")
    nickName = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Random Room")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullName

class Type(models.Model):
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Temperature", unique = True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="C", blank=True)
    VALUE_TYPES = (
               ('float', 'float'),
               ('boolean', 'boolean'),
               ('integer', 'integer'),
               ('string', 'string'),
                          )
    value_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=VALUE_TYPES, default = "float")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quantity

class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Unidentified Device",unique=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True,)
    indigoId = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="000")

    def __unicode__(self):
        #r = Room.objects.get(pk = self.room)
        return self.name #+ ' in room ' + r.name

    def latestMeasurement(self,*args):
        if len(args)==0:
            #No argument so just return latest argument
            meas = Measurement.objects.filter(device=self).latest('date')
        else:
            #Use first argument as the type
            meas = Measurement.objects.filter(device=self, quantity=args[0]).latest('date')
        if not meas:
            return None
        else:    
            return meas

    def typeList(self):
        return Type.objects.filter(measurement__device=self).distinct()


class Measurement(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    quantity = models.ForeignKey(Type)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('date','device','quantity',)
        index_together = ['date', 'device']

    def __unicode__(self):
        t = self.quantity
        return str(self.value) + " " + self.quantity.unit
        # return str(self.value)
```

Comment: How fast is `logDevice`? i see it doesn't save changes in db until it finish `prepareMeasurement`

Comment: also how many rows you are processing?

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if you post your models

Comment: @ahmed : LogDevice typically takes a second or so. Each callback saves a few rows in the database, at most 4 of them. On the other hand it is called up quite frequently, sometimes every second, most of the time every few seconds

Comment: "Note that this script is always running and waiting for more measurements to execute the logDevice callback." this code would also be usefull

Comment: @e4c5: Well a custom library based on yarp takes care of that. Code looks like that:
    'portid = self.createPort(quer.group(1),True,True)  #creates a port
    pyarp.connect(desc[0], self.fullPortPath(portid))    #establishes connection to talking port
    self.listenToPort(portid, lambda port: self.logDevice(port))  #tells him to execute that callback when he receives messages'
I don't think that's very enlightening but I don't really see what else I can say. Callbacks are entirely dealt with in the background.

Comment: could you add that to the question. Unreadable as a comment.